# Why does this function throw an error?

Tags: python-3.x

The below function works fine:

```
def ex():
    for x in a:
        print(x)   
a=[200]
ex()
```

But the below throws a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment" error

```
def ex():
    for x in a:
        print(x)   
    a=0
a=[200]
ex()
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the `a` refers to the global variable `a`. In the second, python interprets your line `a=0` and because of this, it thinks that you mean the local variable. To fix the error, you can give `a` as a second param or write `global a` as the first line of the function